# rmarkdown matrices not functioning as expected or seen in rstudio

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying create a blogdown post using Rmarkdown but the matrix I am trying to create is not giving the correct output. In Rstudio it looks like the image below, however when I run the rmarkdown I get a different result.

[image]

Gives output in blogdown:

[image]

Rmarkdown code:

```
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
\text{var } & ...  & -1 \\
\text{cov } & ...  & ...\\
\text{mat } & ...  & -1 \\
...         & ...  & -1\\
1           & ...  & 0
\end{array}\right)

\left(\begin{array}{c} 
w_{1} \\
... \\
... \\
... \\
w_{k} \\
\lambda
\end{array}\right)

=

\left(\begin{array}{c} 
0 \\
... \\
... \\
... \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right)
$$
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong and how I can make a matrix equation be on the same line as in the RStudio output?

Comment: In hindsight, this is related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230338

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty lines are breaking things. From https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230338

> An empty line in TeX should never be used just to arrange the source. It is an instruction exactly the same as the command \par which ends a paragraph and starts TeX's line breaking algorithm to split a paragraph into lines.
>
> So it is not allowed in display math and it should never be used on the line before display math either, in that position it does not generate an error but forces TeX to take recovery action that produces a spurious white paragraph on the line above the display.
>
> - David Carlisle, Feb 26 '15 at 21:29

While it might not seem obvious that a LaTeX limitation would impose itself on an HTML target, the rendering uses MathJax (javascript library) that renders LaTeX math mode.

If you remove them, it seems to render correctly.

```
---
title: Quux
output: html_document
---

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
\text{var } & ...  & -1 \\
\text{cov } & ...  & ...\\
\text{mat } & ...  & -1 \\
...         & ...  & -1\\
1           & ...  & 0
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} 
w_{1} \\
... \\
... \\
... \\
w_{k} \\
\lambda
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{c} 
0 \\
... \\
... \\
... \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right)
$$
```

[image: rmarkdown rendering into HTML]

It also works with `output: pdf_document`:

[image: rmarkdown rendering into PDF]

```r
R.version
#                _                           
# platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
# arch           x86_64                      
# os             mingw32                     
# system         x86_64, mingw32             
# status                                     
# major          3                           
# minor          5.3                         
# year           2019                        
# month          03                          
# day            11                          
# svn rev        76217                       
# language       R                           
# version.string R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
# nickname       Great Truth                 

packageVersion("knitr")
# [1] '1.23'
packageVersion("rmarkdown")
# [1] '1.13'
```